# BN-280 GPS Error, can't find satellite,

Tags: gps, serial-port, android-gps

How do i fix this?

It doesn't find any satellites, It doesn't show the time.
It does pickup some US satellites once every 5 or so minutes, but with extremely weak signal and it cant get even a 2d fix.
One time i left it running for 10 minutes and at one point it got a 3d fix somewhere in the middle of the ocean.

I think the on board time is broken?

I have it connected to serial and its outputting this:

```
$GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*4D
$GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
$GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
$GPGSV,1,1,00*79
$GLGSV,1,1,00*65
$GNGLL,,,,,,V,N*7A
```

It was working fine a few days ago, then i soldered some shorter wires onto it.

Comment: I guess you've answered yourself - "It was working fine a few days ago, then i soldered some shorter wires onto it"

Comment: Is the aerial outside?